# Dealing with zero at high precision

Tags: polynomials, arbitrary-precision

I am using mathematica to deal with rational functions, $p(x)/q(x)$, where the polynomials, $p,q$ have a high degree and coefficients with high order of precision, e.g:

```
Precision/@CoefficientList[p[x],x]
Out: {350,350,350,...}
```

The problem is that I need use values of that are shifted from `x`, and the rational function then look like

```
rational = p[x+7]/q[x+3]
Out:  (a[1] x+ a[2]x^2+...)/(0.*10^-280+b[1]x+...)
```

where `a[n],b[n]` are actual numbers. By shifting from x, I of course lose some precision, which I am okay-ish with (also I wouldn't mind be able to get higher precision).

When I use `rational` as a rational function everything works fine, but I sometimes need it evaluated at `x=0`. If I do so using `rational/.x->0`, I get the following error:

```
"Infinite expression 1/0.*10^-280 encountered"
```

whereas the correct answer should be `a[1]/b[1]`. I managed to fix this error by using

```
Chop[rational,10^-279]/.x->0
```

which gives me the correct answer. I however have a lot of different polynomials and the loss of precision changes depending on their degree, coeffiients, etc.

the rational function is an approximation of a function, which I *know* is non-singular at the evaluated point, so I know that this precision zero is spurious. The coefficients are however generated by another program I do not have control over, only the high precision. Of course that does not help here because demanding a higher precision I only push the problem forward.

Is there a best-practice way of dealing with that kind of problem?

Comment: Does `rational /. c_Real /; c == 0 -> 0` instead of `Chop` work?  Looks like it might be best if `rational = p[x+7]/q[x+3]  /. c_Real /; c == 0 -> 0` were used to define `rational`. Might also want to make sure the fraction is reduced, maybe with `Simplify`.

Comment: Mathematically, `c_Real /; c == 0 -> 0` amounts to the assumption that any coefficient in which the round-off error bound (computed by the arbitrary-precision arithmetic) is greater than the estimated value should in fact be equal to zero.  (When the error is greater than the value, the number is represented by ```0``n```.)  The method `Chop[rational, 10-^n]` represents the assumption that any coefficient whose value is less than `10^-n` should in fact be zero. The difference is similar to the difference between relative and absolute error respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Michael E2 indicated in the comments using

```
rational = p[x+7]/q[x+3] /. c_Real /; c == 0 -> 0
```

is the best way to get rid of the spurious zero, as `Chop` will also potentially discard small values, and one does not need to look at what the precision of `0.` is.